# Best approach to get registers with timestamp > value

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a synchronization algorithm for exchanging data Client - Server. I need the server to return all registers with timestamp greater than a value given by the Client to get all new data. With the current approach the client only sends the server the latest timestamp for every table via json.
The problem is that it is common (not so common, but possible) to find multiple records with the same timestamp value. I would like the Client to send exactly which was the latest record to download, in case of conflict with same timestamps. I give you an example:

```
+-----+-------------+---------------+
| id  |  Name       | timestamp     |
+-----+-------------+---------------+
| 10    Item 1        1365011940    |
|                                   |
| 11    Item 2        1365011940    |
|                                   |
| 12    Item 3        1365011940    |
+-----+-------------+---------------+
```

Let's say the latest register the Client has is the id 11. With the actual approach, if the clients asks the Server for registers with ts > 1365011940, the register with id = 12 would be omitted. So I want a reliable way to get all the data. I suppose the Client should send also the id of the latest register, in order to sort the registers by the timestamp, id.

What do you think would be the best approach? And, if possible, give me an example of how the query would be.

**NOTE:** registers with the lower ids not necessarily has the lower timestamps, since the field tells when was last updated.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question: If you change your query condition to >=, you will be able to ensure you pull all of the data that is potentially relevant.

As a note of importance: Any time you work with this kind of data syncing, you'll need to anticipate duplicate data. You should be able to identify and discard duplicate records within the client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if the Client requested only 5 records each time? With this approach, and having multiple registers with the same timestamp in the worst possible scenario, Client side could get same 5 registers with the same timestamp all the time. I don't want to avoid duplicates but find the best possible approach.

Comment: If you're limited by the number of results being returned, you'll need to implement a method of tracking progress. Perhaps create a new table which just has an auto_increment field, a reference to this table's ID, and a timestamp. The client should then reference the ID of this new table as the last-pulled data. That way, you have a sequential list of changes, and a definite starting point for your next request